# Can I use 3.7V battery on a 3.5v rated halogen lamp?

Tags: batteries, lamp, halogen

I have a retinoscope that is 3.5v rated and I am searching for battery replacement, the batter I am getting is a 3.7v li-on and the battery which is used in the retinoscope is 3.5v ni-cd, can I use the 3.7v to light up the 3.5v halogen lamp in the retinoscope?
(Note the 3.7v li-on battery can reach its max voltage up to 3.9v and if over charger 4.2v)

Answer (score 0):

Tungsten incandescent lamps are very sensitive to over-voltage: [5% voltage increase cuts lamp life approximately in half](http://www.lamptech.co.uk/Documents/IN%20Voltage.htm).

Likely the retinoscope would work, appearing a bit brighter than normal, but the lamp would fail about twice as frequently.

Two simple work-arounds:

- If you know the lamps *current* requirements, a small series resistor would greatly increase life. Please *add to the question* the halogen lamp's model and/or current rating.
- Only charge the battery to 3.5 V. The battery [would last a shorter time](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-501a-discharge-characteristics-of-li-ion) between charges, though.

BTW, How can the old Ni-Cd battery be rated *3.5 VDC*? The chemistry of Ni-Cd cells is such that each provides [between 1.3 and 1.45 V](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-407-charging-nickel-cadmium), depending on charge state. One cell give ~1.4 V; two cells in series, 2.8 V, and three yields 4.2 V. Double-check that battery rating! If you assume because the *lamp* is rated 3.5 V, that does not mean the *battery* is.